# Is there any possible way to grab direct link from mediafire sharing link

Tags: javascript

Mediafire is a free storage site. I want to grab a direct download link from mediafire but it is giving me either shareable link or temporary link. Is there any possible to grab direct link.

here is the link - `https://www.mediafire.com/file/0m3dqqbjl66ib45/yPQG1n5yd1j2KEWzC5cejyKX9Iy9IOBzFKrRRKMj.jpg/file`

Thank you in Advance

I have tried using 3rd party link grabber sites

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the download button and press Inspect Element. The direct download link should be located on the `href` attribute of the button:[image]

Comment: that's just a temporary link.